Inverting an irregular gap in a GeoTIFF?
Here's the situation...
I want to make a 3D map of Palmyra Atoll, which looks like this:

And so I secured from NOAA a GeoTIFF of this 5m grid:

...which looks like this:

When I use TouchTerrain to render the 3D map, it looks like this:

Where the land around the central lagoon should be there's a depression instead of a protrusion; this is because the gaps in the GeoTIFF are rendered as black instead of white.
Is there an easy way to adjust the color of the gap?
